# I am trying to to set up secure tls communication using mqtt and node js and Getting error Client mqtt_79ea02ba6396 disconnected, not authorise

Tags: node.js, mqtt, node-modules, tls1.2, secure-gateway

I have created self signed certificate using openssl and put generated certificate in the folder and gave the path in the code as well as in the mosquitto.conf file.

I have created a index.js file as follow:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(\__dirname, 'certs', 'server.key'))
const CERT = fs.readFileSync(path.join(\__dirname, 'certs','server.crt'))
const TRUSTED_CA_LIST = fs.readFileSync(path.join(\__dirname, 'certs','ca.crt'))
const PASSWORD = fs.readFileSync(path.join(\__dirname, 'password', 'passwd_mqtt'))
const USERNAME = 'user1'

const PORT = 8883
const HOST = 'localhost'
const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`
const connectUrl = `mqtts://${HOST}:${PORT}`

const options = {
clientId,
clean: true,
port: PORT,
host: HOST,
key: KEY,
cert: CERT,
password: PASSWORD,
username: USERNAME,
rejectUnauthorized: false,
// The CA list will be used to determine if server is authorized
ca: TRUSTED_CA_LIST,
protocol: 'mqtts',
protocolId: 'MQTT',
protocolVersion: 5,
connectTimeout:1000,
debug:true
}

const client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl,options)

client.on('connect', function () {
console.log('Connected')
})

client.on('error', function (error) {
console.log(error)
})
client.subscribe('messages')

client.publish('messages', 'Current time is: ' + new Date())
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
console.log(message)
})
```

my mosquitto.conf file is as follow:

```
listener 8883
allow_anonymous false
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true
protocol mqtt
persistence true
allow_zero_length_clientid true
log_type all
connection_messages true
max_connections -1
password_file /Users/mithila/mqtt_node_tls/password/passwd_mqtt
cafile /Users/mithila/mqtt_node_tls/certs/ca.crt
keyfile /Users/mithila/mqtt_node_tls/certs/server.key
certfile /Users/mithila/mqtt_node_tls/certs/server.crt
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

after running index.js file I am getting following error:

```
Error: Connection refused: Bad User Name or Password
code: 134
```

and i am getting error on local mosquito terminal as:

```
1648034540: Sending CONNACK to mqtt_e32d3293f5b1 (0, 134)
1648034540: Client mqtt_e32d3293f5b1 disconnected, not authorised.
```

I have created password file using command:

```
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd_mqtt
```

I have tried all possible solutions given in the various blog like creating user certificate and password file

Comment: The command to create/edit the mosquitto password file is `mosquitto_passwd`

Comment: Also you probably should not be using the same certificate to identify both the broker and the client, and with `use_identity_as_username true` the password file will need to contain the client certificate's CN value, not `user1`.  I suggest you start again and carefully consider what each mosquitto configuration option does and add them back if needed one at a time.

Comment: i have created client certificate using the same CA file which i used to create server cert. put client cert along with ca.crt in option of index.js and removed the password file. I am not getting any error on client but server side i mean on terminal where mosquitto is running I am getting error as :
````
1648047075: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate
1648047075: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
````

Comment: That should have been an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71586549/edit) to the question. You have now changed so much the original question doesn't match the problem.